# Getting 404 Errors when Trying to Access API Endpoint in cPanel-hosted Express.js App

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cpanel

I'm hosting a Node.js application on cPanel, and I'm encountering 404 errors when trying to access an API endpoint in my application. Here are the details of my setup:

Directory Structure:

```
public_html/
    server.mjs
    index.html
    node_modules
```

server.mjs:

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import OpenAI from 'openai';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const apiKey = ''; // Replace with your actual OpenAI API key

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: apiKey,
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public_html'))); // Serve files from public_html
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Add a GET route for /chat
app.get('https://www.mazzn.info/chat', (req, res) => {
  res.send('This is the chat page. You can use it for testing or debugging.');
});

// POST route for /chat
app.post('https://www.mazzn.info/chat', async (req, res) => {
  const { msgp1 } = req.body;
  let message = `Answer to this message as a doctor ${msgp1}`;

  // Use OpenAI API to generate a response
  try {
    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: message }],
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    });

    const chatbotResponse = completion.choices[0].message.content;

    res.json({ chatbotResponse });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., display an error message to the user
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching the response from the chatbot.' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

index.html

```html
     <div class="card">
 
       <div class="chat-header">دردشة</div>
        <div class="chat-window" id="chat-window">
            <ul class="message-list" id="message-list">
                <!-- Messages will be added here dynamically -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-input">
            <input type="text" class="message-input" placeholder="أكتب رسالتك هنا">
            <button class="send-button rounded" onclick="sendMessage()" style="background-color: #db3700;">أرسل</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        async function sendMessage() {
            var messageInput = document.querySelector('.message-input');
            var messageList = document.querySelector('.message-list');
            var message = messageInput.value;
    
            if (message.trim() === '') {
                return;
            }
    
            // Display user message
            var userMessageContainer = document.createElement('li'); // Change from <div> to <li>
            userMessageContainer.classList.add('user-message');
            userMessageContainer.textContent = message;
            messageList.appendChild(userMessageContainer);
    
            messageInput.value = '';
            scrollToLatestMessage();
    
            // Send user message to the chatbot and display response
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/chat', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ message }),
                });
    
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('API request failed with status ' + response.status);
                }
    
                const responseData = await response.json();
                const chatbotResponse = responseData.chatbotResponse;
    
                // Display chatbot response
                var chatbotMessageContainer = document.createElement('li'); // Change from <div> to <li>
                chatbotMessageContainer.classList.add('chatbot-message');
                chatbotMessageContainer.textContent = chatbotResponse;
                messageList.appendChild(chatbotMessageContainer);
    
                // Log chatbot response to the console
                console.log('Chatbot Response:', chatbotResponse);
    
                scrollToLatestMessage();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                // Handle the error gracefully, e.g., display an error message to the user
                alert('An error occurred while fetching the response from the chatbot.');
            }
        }
    
        function scrollToLatestMessage() {
            var chatWindow = document.getElementById('chat-window');
            chatWindow.scrollTop = chatWindow.scrollHeight;
        }
    </script>
```

I've set up a simple chat application where users can send messages to a chatbot. The issue arises when trying to send a POST request to the /chat endpoint; I get a 404 error.

I've confirmed that the server is running, and I've double-checked the route definitions. I suspect that the issue might be related to how cPanel handles routing and endpoints.

Could someone please help me identify the problem and suggest a solution to make the API endpoint accessible within my cPanel-hosted application?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error when you visit `https://www.mazzn.info/chat`?

Comment: change `app.get('https://www.mazzn.info/chat',` to `app.get('/chat',`, and try it again.

Comment: Yeah, am getting 404 and i try both of the /chat or https://www.mazzn.info/chat. can you think with other possible thing do this problem ?

Comment: You need to add more details to your question, such as "package.json" content.

Comment: Try running the `tree` command in the project root, adding the output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  app.get('https://www.mazzn.info/chat'
> ```

The first argument should be the local **path**, not an absolute URL.

That should be `app.get('/chat',` with similar changes for all  your other routes.

---

> ```
> public_html/
>     server.mjs
> ```

Your server side code should **not** be exposed to the public.

> ```
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public_html')));
> ```

You are looking for static files in a *public_html* directory that is at the same level as the *server.mjs*. Since *server.mjs* is inside that directory (which it shouldn't be, as I mentioned above) you won't find them.

---

The use of a *public_html* directory is quite common for shared hosting using Apache.

I've never seen it for a Node.js application.

Make sure the hosting serving you are using actually supports Node.js applications and that you are deploying it correctly.